# Matrix representation of polynomials of degree 1

Tags: linear-algebra, linear-transformations

Let $V$ be the vector space of polynomials of 1st order and $W$ be the vector space of polynomials of 2nd order. Consider the linear mapping $$I: V \to W: If(x) = \int_{0}^{x} f(t) dt$$.

Now I have to find the matrix representaiton of $A_{B,C}$ of $I$ w.r.t. basis $B=\{1,x\}$ on $V$ and $C=\{1,x,x^{2}\}$ on $W$.

I would have done it as following:

$$If(1)= x = a_{1,1}  * 1 +   a_{2,1}*x  + a_{3,1}  * x^{2}$$
$$If(x)= \frac{x^{2}}{2} = a_{1,2}  * 1 +   a_{2,2}*x  + a_{3,2}  * x^{2}$$

Solving this leads to

$$A_{B,C} = \begin{pmatrix}
        0 & 0 \\
        1 & 0 \\
        0 & 1/2  \\
        \end{pmatrix} $$

Is this the right approach or have I done a mistake. I am still a little bit confused with the topic. Thanks!

Comment: This is correct. One nitpick: $If(1)$ and $If(x)$ should instead be written $I(1)$ and $I(x)$.

Comment: I just asked myself if $I$ is surjective and I would say yes since $im(f) = W$ - with the integral of $V$ I can generate every member of $W$. Is this guess right? But how could i formally show this?

Comment: How would you generate $1$ using the operator $I$?

Comment: Mhm well I did not thought about that case. So it is not surjective. Thanks!